# How to trace a fatal error with Xcode and Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8, fatal-error

I am trying to test a simple a program I have made while learning swift programming, but I always get a fatal error, and nothing will be shown.

I tried to copy my code to a playground, but there the custom classes I created are not recognized?

Comment: Could you show the code where the error occurs and what kind of error it is ?

Comment: http://jeffreysambells.com/2014/01/14/using-breakpoints-in-xcode

Answer (score 0):

I found the error that one of the buttons is referencing the wrong outlet. This outlet was created by mistake, and it is name is the same as one of the Actions.